# how to make android service to pass data to url

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-service, android-networking

i have already finished code to passing data to url , and it did successfully .
but now i need to this in the background ,So i make a service to do this even the application is ended .
my problem when i started the service it pass data once ,but i need to pass data every interval of time so How to do that ??

this is my code

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
 return null;
 }
Random r;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
player.stop();
}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Log.d(TAG, "onStart");


 r=new Random();
 //
 int o=r.nextInt(1000);
 HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://androidsaveitem.appspot.com/save");
 List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description+", "description FOR id     "+String.valueOf(o)));
 formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id+", String.valueOf(o)));
 UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;
try {
entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams);
postMethod.setEntity(entity);
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {
HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

in the activity i write this

```
     startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

i have already write the permission in the manifest file

```
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: mmm where can i make this ???

Comment: please can you write the code for the timer

Comment: thanksss
but it didn't work there is no data pass to the url :(

Comment: it fill with null but not when i run the program , is it from you ?

Comment: yes,code  perfectly working but u have some other issue maybe with your database.see my edit post

Comment: yes i there are new data and nulls
you use the same code???

Comment: ok thanks 
but can you use the alarm ??

Comment: listen ,, i need to do this in the background completely ... i don't want any enter action from user

Comment: and i need to be long interval between this actions 
so the Alarm is a good for me

Comment: there is intent must show ???
i need to do all thing in background

Comment: my service it remind the same ,, that mean i just the way i call the service just by alarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than leaving your `Service` running in the background all the time (unless it's constantly doing work!), you should probably consider registering an alarm with the OS that will wake up your service at specified intervals and then let it go back to sleep when it's finished.

This will simplify your `Service` implementation and free you from most of the timing related issues.  You will also get the benefit that if your `Service` crashes or is killed for some reason, the alarm timer will bring it back on the next cycle.

The way it works is by creating a `BroadcastReceiver` that is listening for a particular `Intent` that you've registered with [Android's `AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Which option you choose will largely depend on how big your intervals are, since broadcasting an alarm is much more expensive than having a timer wait.  If you want to do your work every few seconds, the timer is probably better.  If your wait times are measured in minutes or hours, do the alarm thing.

First, you'll need to create the alarm.

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, yourIntent, yourFlags);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManger.ELAPSED_REALTIME, // Alarm type 
                       5000,                         // Time before first alarm
                       AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,   // Alarm interval
                       pi);                          // Sent when alarm happens
```

To actually make use of the alarm, you have to listen for it to go off.  For that, you need to create a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

```
public class SnoozeButton extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (thisIntentIsTheOneIWant(intent){
            context.startService(intent);
        }
    }

    private boolean thisIntentIsTheOneIWant(Intent intent) {
        // Test here to make sure this intent is for your app 
        // and service.  You may get Intents other than what
        // you are interested in.
    }
}
```

Note that you must declare your `BroadcastReciever` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: yes i need alarm ,, cause i need the interval almost long
but can you give me an example to do that ?

Comment: @Hanaa I don't have time to elaborate right now.  I'll try to whip up an example for you later today.

Comment: @Hanaa I had an extra few minutes after all.  I've edited my answer to provide an example.  Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you ..
but what about intent i don't need to view the action to user
i just need to do in background

Comment: >>>
the BroadcastReceiver how can i fill it ??? or the methods above what can i make them 
how to listening for my Intent ??

Comment: An `Intent` can start a `Service` (which runs without any UI), not just an `Activity`.  As you can see in my example, everything refers to `Service`, not `Activity`.  Except for testing the `Intent` to make sure it's the one you're interested in (check for the package name at a minimum), that's pretty much the whole thing.